# How are people authenticated in their ASP.NET Core Web APIs on Ubuntu/Docker given the bug described below?

Tags: authentication, docker, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04, .net-core

I have come across what I think is a bug preventing me from loading an X509Certificate2 on Ubuntu or the Debian-based docker image provided by Microsoft.  This means that I can't initialise JwtAuthentication in my web API on these platforms, and I'm looking for help:

1. Are you successfully using JwtAuthentication on Linux?
2. If so, how are you initialising an X509Certificate for the JwtBearerOptions?
3. Can you see a problem with what I'm doing, or suggest a work-around or solution?

I have logged the issue with the corefx team and you can see the full discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16029), but below is the main description of the problem:

---

I have a Web API running in a docker container.  The container is built from the provided 1.1.0 package:

```
  FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.0
```

and the Web API binaries are copied in.    The API runs fine and returns data as expected until I turn on authentication, at which point it needs an X509SecurityKey to set the *TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey* value.  It throws an exception when it attempts to initialise an X509Certificate2 from a string value:

```
    string certValue = certificate.Value;
    byte[] byteCert = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(certValue);
    return new X509Certificate2(byteCert);
```

throws an OpenSslCryptographicException:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Failed to extract the Token Signing certificate from the Federation metadata. ---> 
    Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
       at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlob(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] data)
       at Mercury.Shared.Rest.Authentication.AdfsFederationMetadata.GetSigningCertificate()
```

The string value from which the  X509Certificate2 is being initialised is:

```
    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
```

The same code runs with no problem on Windows, building a certificate from the same string.

**Edit:** *Note that while I initially encountered this problem running a docker image, subsequent testing has shown that it also occurs using Ubuntu 14.04 + .NET Core 1.1*

Comment: Have you tried to decode (from Base64) the string before you pass it to the contructor?

Comment: Nice job Salem, that did it!  I changed my code from `var byteCert = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(certString);` to `var byteCert = Convert.FromBase64String(certString);` before calling `new X509Certificate2(byteCert)` and it now works on Windows, Ubuntu and Docker.  Please put in an answer to this effect and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that what is being passed to the constructor are the bytes of the base64 representation of the key, and not the bytes of the key itself.

If this code works on Windows then maybe it's a good idea to create an issue in the .net core github referencing this problem.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.  Just to note for others that the Linux implementation (which wraps the openssl libraries) and the Windows implementation work slightly inconsistently: where Windows will handle either the Base64-encoded bytes or the decoded version, on Linux you must decode as shown here.  I have brought this to the attention of the corefx team in my [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16029).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answer. For those who would like to copy and paste:

```
var certificateWithoutHeaderAndFooter = certificateString
         .Replace("\\n","")
         .Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "") 
         .Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");

var certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateWithoutHeaderAndFooter);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBase64Bytes);
```